# Submenu displaying in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, submenu

Here is the testing site link.I encountered the problem that displaying the sub-menu 
[link](http://vygears.com/stockholm/index.html)

In that navigation bar "why stockholm " when I hover it ,displayed the submenu also and when i hover the submenu its working normal wat i am doing wrong anyone much appreciated..

```
(function($){

    //cache nav
    var nav = $("#topNav");

    //add indicator and hovers to submenu parents
    nav.find("li").each(function() {
        if ($(this).find("ul").length > 0) {
            $("<span>").text("").appendTo($(this).children(":first"));

            //show subnav on hover
            $(this).mouseenter(function() {
                $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideDown();
            });

            //hide submenus on exit
            $(this).mouseleave(function() {
                $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideUp();
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Please post some code (but not all of it)

Comment: I added the code of js and also the testing link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `children()` instead of `find()`. When you use `find('ul')` it uses all `ul` inside your selector.

[**Here is working jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/wzh74/3/)

```
        //show subnav on hover
        $(this).mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).children("ul").stop(true, true).slideDown();
        });

        //hide submenus on exit
        $(this).mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).children("ul").stop(true, true).slideUp();
        });
```